# Value_counts not returning the desired output

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, series

I'm trying to get the most common value of a column based on another column. 
Specifically, I'm using this code:

```
data.beds[data.bedrooms== 1].value_counts()
```

This has worked before but now the output I get is

```
Series([], Name: beds, dtype: int64)
```

The data looks like this:

```
bedrooms     beds
0             1
1             1
1             1
0             1
2             2
...          ...
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how can I fix it in order to get the actual value? This worked a few days ago, so I have really no idea what's wrong!

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Can you add a [mcve]?

Comment: I managed to fix it! Apparently I had forgotten to run the line of code that converts it to numeric (as this line was of object type because it had strings). Without converting it to numeric, the solution was to do data.beds[data.bedrooms== ''1''].value_counts()

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it! After looking at here for so long my brain stopped working.

Apparently I had forgotten to run the line of code that converts it to numeric (as this line was of object type because it had strings). Without converting it to numeric, the solution was to do data.beds[data.bedrooms== ''1''].value_counts()

Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Try `data[data.bedrooms==1].beds.value_counts()` or even `data[data.bedrooms==1].beds.mode()` since you want the values that appear most often.

Comment: It still doesn't work... doesn't return the actual value...

Comment: please share an example of the dataframe you're using.

Comment: Ended up realising that I had to convert everything to numeric first, as this column still had strings!! It works now!! Obrigada na mesma :)

Answer (score 0):

You are making a filter before applying the value_counts() (all rows with bedroom value = 1 [data.bedrooms== 1])

That first filter is returning no values, that is why you get the shown output:
Series([], Name: beds, dtype: int64)

You cannot obtain the value counts on an empty dataset.

regards!